# Sqlite executeSql is not returning ResultSet

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am attempting to perform a simple query with `Sqlite` in `React-Native` using the [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) plugin.  Based on the documentation I should get two paramters into the success callback 1) the `SQLite.Transaction` and 2) `SQLlite.ResultSet`  but I am only getting the `SQLite.Transaction` in my example.

```
let sql = "SELECT * FROM table_a;"
let params = [];

db.executeSql(sql, params,
  (trans, results) => {
    console.log("execute success results: " + JSON.stringify(results))
    console.log("execute success transaction: " + JSON.stringify(trans))
    //resolve(results);
    resolve(trans);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("execute error: " + error);
    reject(error);
});
```

**Console output**

```
execute success results: undefined
execute success transaction: {"rows":{"length":1},"rowsAffected":0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to wrap my `executeSql` in a `transaction`.  This works as expected:

```
db.transaction((txn) => {
    txn.executeSql(sql, params, (trans, results) => {
        console.log("execute success results: " + JSON.stringify(results))
        console.log("execute success transaction: " + JSON.stringify(trans))
        //resolve(results);
        resolve(trans);
    },
        (error) => {
        console.log("execute error: " + JSON.stringify(error))
        reject(error);
    });
});
```